# If $V = U\oplus W$ as vector spaces, and we have a section $s\colon U \to V$ to the projection map, does that mean $V = s(U) \oplus W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $V = U\oplus W$. Let $p_1\colon V\to U$ be the canonical projection map.

Suppose there is a section $s\colon U \to V$ such that $p_1\circ s = id_U$.

Does that mean $V = s(U) \oplus W$?

I think it is true. I think I can prove it by considering the intersection of $s(U)$ and $W$ and count dimensions after that. Another way is probably by considering the splitting lemma. But I am worried this means the direct sum (or any direct sum) decomposition is not that canonical.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you concluded thus far? What are you confused about?

Comment: @amWhy I think it is true. I think I can prove it by considering the intersection of $s(U)$ and $W$ and count dimensions after that. Another way is probably by considering the splitting lemma. But I am worried this means the direct sum (or any direct sum) decomposition is not that canonical

Comment: I edited your question this time, thanks to the thoughts you placed in the comments.  In the future, comments and thoughts like you posted above count as context, so try to include them in your questions.

Comment: Since $s$ is injective, $s(U) \cong U$ via $s(u) \mapsto u$.

Comment: @azif00 we have $V \simeq s(U) \oplus W$. But do we have $V = s(U) \oplus W$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As azifoo has noted, $s(U)\simeq U$, and so in particular has the same dimension as $U$. So by dimension counting, you just need to show that $s(U)\cap W = \{0\}$. To do this, suppose $x\in s(U)\cap W$. Then $x=s(u)$ for some $u\in U$, and so $p_1(x) = p_1(s(u)) = u$. However since $x\in W$, $p_1(x) = 0$. So $u=0\implies x=s(u) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if $j : W \to V$ is the inclusion, and $\tilde s : U \to s(U)$ is the map $u \mapsto s(u)$, then since
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> W @>j>> V @>{p_1}>> U @>>> 0 \\
@. @| @| @VV{\tilde s}V \\
0 @>>> W @>>j> V @>>{\tilde s \circ p_1}> s(U) @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$
commutes, the top row is exact, and all the vertical maps are isomorphisms, it follows that the bottom row is also exact, and then $V = s(U) \oplus W$ (the canonical projection $p_2 : V \to W$ is a retraction for $j$).